# Logic app - Retrieve email content as-is format from storage blob URL

Tags: html, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

I am using the Azure logic app. I am scraping email content as it is (with images/text) and storing it in azure blob storage but when I hit the blob url it's showing me pure HTML. I have modified the content type of a "created blob" action but no change. How can I retrieve the same content in an as-is format?

Answer (score 0):

I have added the content type as "text/html". it worked for me.
[image]